# "Publicity" centered on 'events' and the bigger question of events in general

Tags: discussion, publicity

The se blog post [does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) says:

> "Joel suggested a healthier alternative by rallying users around
>   specific events as a catalyst for asking interesting questions you
>   come across in your day to day work. Any event that gets your
>   community going — a hot new release, an upcoming convention, any
>   news-worthy event" 
>   and then goes on to give an example where it worked.

This seems like a good idea to me for genealogy.se. What are events 'worthy' of us doing Q&A pushes around?

This raises the question of types of events and what is in scope for genealogy.se. Clearly 'events' like the release of the US 1940 census data are broad enough to both be within scope and to rate a Q&A push as part of promoting the site. But an event like a monthly meeting of a local genealogy society wouldn't rate a Q&A push (albeit some have more active members than this site does at the moment). What about something like [RootsTech](http://rootstech.org/) or [NEHGS Ancestry Day](http://www.americanancestors.org/ancestry-day/)? They are not events like the release of the 1940 census data (which remains as a resource forever) but are actual events. Are they in-scope for asking questions about and are they appropriate to have Q&A pushes around?

For any of these, what is right mechanism to 'start a Q&A push' around an event? I presume it would be a meta question dedicated to that 'push', tagged with publicity, and hopefully 'promoted' to be on the main site sidebar.

Are there any upcoming events we can trial this process with?

Answer (score 1):

One problem with events is that they are localized to a specific time frame. After the event is over, the question no longer has much relevance.

Localized by time frame is one of the reasons for closing questions.

Comment: We need to be careful about how we interpret "localised". The 1922 bombardment of the Four Courts in Dublin was localised in both time and space but it continues to have enormous impact on the practice of Irish genealogy. "Are you going to Roots Tech?" should obviously be closed, but "Roots Tech is discussing FHISO, so let's target questions on standards at that time" could be a valid strategy.