# Q&A "pushes" around Who Do You Think You Are Live and RootsTech

Tags: discussion, publicity

Duncan suggested at ["Publicity" centered on 'events' and the bigger question of events in general](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1554/104) that we do Q&A pushes around 'specific events' and there are two major events coming up that I wonder if we can capitalise on.

1. [Who Do You Think Your Are Live](http://www.whodoyouthinkyouarelive.com/) which is "the biggest family history event in the world", taking place from 22-24 February in London, England.
2. [RootsTech](http://rootstech.org/), taking place from 21-23 March in Salt Lake City, Utah.

One good focus for both events would be questions around starting out in Genealogy.

For WDYTYA, another focus might be research in the United Kingdom.

For RootsTech, another focus might be the use of technology to support research.

In all cases, the objective ought to be to generate some excellent content (questions and answers) in advance as well as during the events that will be found via search engines by people coming away from the event and wanting to follow up on what they've seen or learned.

Views?

Of course, if anyone is attending either event, it would be nice to generate some publicity for us, but I don't know (a) how comfortable people would be doing that and (b) how realistic a goal it would be at such big events.

Comment: I have updated my GFH flyer in case anyone would like to use it for the above events: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1217522/gfh_flyer.pdf

Comment: Also, the InDesign source and linked files are archived here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1217522/gfh_flyer.zip

Comment: @fbrereto, thanks!

Comment: Good idea. But by "pushes around", do you mean "bullies"? :-)  I'll be telling people about Genealogy SE at the FindMyPast Genealogy Cruise next week.

Comment: @lkessler LOL! And excellent re the FindMyPast cruise. Is it worth updating your Co-ordinating Publicity Q at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1210/104?

Comment: I've updated the Publicity post, adding a conference section.

Comment: You may be able to get some swag to hand out/wear for the event http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/ . There's a GDoc for swag requests as well, but I can't find it. Not sure that this will work, though -- for one, you're still in beta, so you can only get generic swag (unless one of you designs a logo and gives it to Jin or something). Secondly, these things take time, and IIRC you have to submit swag requests a bit early. Still, no harm in asking (Aarthi's the one you should ping about this, IIRC)