# RootsTech 2013 - volunteer for leading publicity

Tags: discussion, publicity

Regarding this [Coordinating Publicity](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/coordinating-publicity) question, that says "Mar 21-23, 2013, need a volunteer to lead publicity" what does that mean? What would a volunteer going to [RootsTech 2013](http://rootstech.org/) be expected to do?

---

**Update:**
K. Would still like more input from other members, but here is what I can do...

1. Update my SE G&FH profile information (so I look like a real person ;)  **√** done
2. Print out a flyer and post it places at the conference.
3. Talk up the community whenever it makes sense to do so.
4. Tweet the conference.
5. Mention hot conference topics/findings in "chat".
6. Create some meta questions as per @Duncan's suggestions.
7. Coordinate a physical meet up of those attending.

Comment: I can print out flyer and get copies made & give to you when we meet.  Since I've never been, I don't know how open they are to flyers from 'non-vendors', maybe someone else here knows where they can be put up.

Comment: @Jeni Oh! I never thought of that. Yeah, we definitely don't want to be flyer-spamming! ...what if we got kicked out!?! horrible

Answer (score 4):

As I said here [Q&A "pushes" around Who Do You Think You Are Live and RootsTech](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1608/104):

> Of course, if anyone is attending either event, it would be nice to generate some publicity for us, but I don't know (a) how comfortable people would be doing that and (b) how realistic a goal it would be at such big events.

If you -- and any other attendees -- could take some of the fliers that fbrereto has linked at [Q&A "pushes" around Who Do You Think You Are Live and RootsTech](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/qa-pushes-around-who-do-you-think-you-are-live-and-rootstech#comment4304_1608) and put them where others can find them, that would be great. And of course mention us enthusiastically whenever appropriate :) Others may have better ideas!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that whoever 'leads publicity for RootsTech 2013' should be a lead of a committee (ie lots can help). The lead should:

- be someone who is attending (but with help from others, particularly others attending and others 'contributing' thru meta Q&A)
- make a meta question of 'who is attending'
- maybe co-ordinate a physical get together (eg meet near wherever at whatever time) of those attending
- look thru existing main and meta for questions about likely 'vendors/booths/bof' that might be there (eg ancestry.com, myheritage.com, wereleate.org, NEHGS, familysearch, gramps, ...) and then craft a meta question about each along the lines of 'how should we promote gfh.se with x at rootstech'. The meta allows the rest of us to help prepare the attendees, particularly in areas they might not be as familiar
- go thru the rest of gfh.se publicity meta to cull out who might know which bloggers and cross-correlate with who might be there so we could get some 'ran into x at rootstech who chatted me up on gfh.se' by the blogosphere
- tweet about event wrt gfh.se
- make and print 'flyers' for attendees to place and handout. We may need two types of flyers - one for attendees on how it would be great if they participated in gfh.se and one for 'vendors' on why it be of value for them to participate in and encourage participation in gfh.se
- look thru other se sites on how they handled the equivilent
- have a meta question for participants to update while at the event so others not there can help and/or stay informed
- is there any way to get something on main se site? rootstech is pretty techy so I'll bet there are lots of rootstech attendees who are already se participants but never noticed gfh.se. If we could get something on rootstech/gfh.se in everybody's sidebar, we might find other friends we didn't even know we had. Something along lines of 'anyone attending rootstech blah blah'.

Comment: Great suggestions!

Comment: @ fbrereto - your flyer is great for attendees.  Duncan suggests one for vendors also - do you have any ideas about that?