# Who is attending RootsTech 2013?

Tags: discussion

As per @Duncan's suggestion "[make a meta question of 'who is attending'](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/rootstech-2013-volunteer-for-leading-publicity/1627#1627)" can we see a show of hands who's going to RootsTech this March?

Comment: Here is a flyer by Fbrereto. Feel free to pass it out and spread the word at the conference. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1217522/gfh_flyer.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I am attending - since I've never been to one, I selected the "Getting Started" for only 39$ early bird price. It lets me into the Expo hall as well.

Comment: Yeah, Jenni! {waves} You are going to have a great time.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be there. I happen to work for FamilySearch and will be giving two presentations for developers.

Comment: Yeah, JustinY! {waves}

Answer (score 1):

FHISO will be at RootsTech--booth and panel discussion in the afternoon on Developer Day. Busy getting everything ready.